# J2ME LWUIT TabbedPane: How to add mutliple components in a tab?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

How can *multiple* components ( for example a `Label`, a `Textfield` and a `Button` ) can be added in a *single* Tab?

I tried creating a new Form with multiple components, then added that form into the TabbedPane as new Tab, but it threw an exception : `java/lang/IllegalArgumentException: A form cannot be added to a container.`

Any help/ideas/hints/links will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TabbedPane works with different components used to display the different tabs.

```
new TabbedPane().addTab(title, component)
```

You need a separate container for each tab not a form!